# Magento Images switcher for custom options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I have created a custom options image switcher for Magento, script compares value from options in drop-down with all image names related to product, and finds the most similar one, you can see an example [here](http://www.i70powersports.com/fox-360-intake-jersey.html)

The problem is how to add the "selected" option image to the cart, or better to say how to apply that image instead of the default thumbnail in the cart?

anyway here is the complete code - maybe someone can even find this part useful :)

```
<?php
// load all images related to product
$product = $this->getProduct();
$galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');


$images_array = array();
foreach ($galleryData['images'] as $image) {
 array_push($images_array, $image['file']);
}?>

<?php
$colour_select_id = '';
$custom_options_arr = array();
foreach ($_options as $_option) {
 if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Helmet Color/Design' || $_option->getTitle() == 'Color')  {
    $colour_select_id = 'select_' . $_option->getId();
    $values = $_option->getValues();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $current_option = ($value->getData());
        $custom_options_arr[$current_option['option_type_id']] = $current_option['title'];
    }
  }
}
// $custom_options_arr now holds key=>value pairs of option_type_id => title

$custom_images_to_output = array();
foreach ($custom_options_arr as $key => $value) {
$best_match = $images_array[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($images_array); $i++) {
    if (similar_text(strtoupper($images_array[$i]), strtoupper($value)) > similar_text(strtoupper($best_match), strtoupper($value))) {
        $best_match = $images_array[$i];
    }
}
$custom_images_to_output[$key] = $best_match;
}
$base_url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product';
?>    

<?php if ($colour_select_id) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var opt_object = <?php echo json_encode($custom_images_to_output); ?>;
        var base_path = '<?= $base_url;?>';

        jQuery("#<?= $colour_select_id ?>").change(function() {

            var optionValue = jQuery(this).attr('value');

            if (optionValue) {
                var optionValueText = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#<?= $colour_select_id ?> :selected').text());
                if (opt_object.hasOwnProperty(optionValue)) {
                    optionValueText = opt_object[optionValue];
                }

                jQuery("#image").fadeOut(function() { 
                  jQuery(this).load(function() { 
                  jQuery(this).fadeIn(); }); 
                  jQuery(this).attr("src", base_path + optionValueText);
                  jQuery('#image-zoom').attr("href", base_path + optionValueText);
                }); 

           }    
        });
    });
</script>
```